# System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid (linq query)

Tags: c#, linq

Specified cast is not valid error at line: select new File.Models.FileDetail(). DTTT in the code is a datatable, FileDetial is a class in a Model which has Filename,Dt,receivedcount,status params. I have checked all the Field datatypes and they are correct. Not sure why I'm getting this error.

```
return (from row in DTTT.AsEnumerable()
                        select new File.Models.FileDetail()
                         {
                             Filename = row.Field<string>("name"),
                             Dt = row.Field<DateTime?>("Dt"),
                             ReceivedCount = row.Field<int?>("count"),
                             status = row.Field<string>("status")

                         }

                    ).ToList();
```

Comment: is `Dt` and `ReceivedCount` are nullable?

Comment: What is their respective DbType - `Filename,Dt,receivedcount,status`, one of them is not the type you are trying to typecast

Comment: What is the return type from the method?

Comment: You should add the exception details you get

Comment: @MrinalKamboj you are right my DT DBtype was char and in model i declared as Datetime. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cast it as a `TimeSpan`:

```
 Dt = row.Field<TimeSpan>("Dt");
```

OR

```
Dt = (DateTime)(row.Field<DateTime>("Dt") == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue :row.Field<DateTime>("Dt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dbtype of my "DT" field is char and the ReceivedCount property field is declared as Datetime in my model. So there was a invalid cast exception. changing my model field datatype to string worked. Thanks everyone.